# How to get unique values from all columns of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 60 columns and I need to get unique values from all the columns using a SQL query. Is it possible in SQL Server?

Note I need to find distinct values from all the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this code

```
declare @Sql_Str varchar(8000)='';
select @Sql_Str=@Sql_Str+' select cast (' +name  +' as varchar(500)) from 
<yourtable> union' from sys.columns where [object_id]=object_id('<yourtable>')
set @Sql_Str=SUBSTRING(@Sql_Str,1,len(@Sql_Str)-6)
exec(@Sql_Str)
```

Comment: It is showing an error that "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: please make sure that you replcae <yourtable> with the actual table in both the places

Comment: you want the unique values for all the columns together or unique values for each individual columns. The above result is  for the former

Comment: @JoeGJoseph Hi Joe, Sorry for digging up this old post. I'm trying to do the same thing as OP. I pasted your code, replaced the table name. But is having this error. `Line 37
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXIT'.`  There are only 5 lines of code and I don't know where the `EXIT` is from.. Could you help me a bit here please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag the columns heading in the SSMS object explorer to the query window.
2. Find and replace the ", " with "\n" using Regular Expressions.
3. Generate a SELECT INTO distinct query for each column using Regular Expressions for each column and assign the output to a temp table built by the Regular Expression.
4. Make use of the data in your temp tables.