# Select all unique values from all columns in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I need to select all unique values from all columns in a table.

I have tried to implement the query below which I found in the thread [How to get unique values from all columns of a table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425341/how-to-get-unique-values-from-all-columns-of-a-table-in-sql-server).

```
declare @Sql_Str varchar(8000)=''; 

select @Sql_Str=@Sql_Str+' select cast (' +name  +' as varchar(500)) 
                           from  <yourtable> union'
from sys.columns 
where [object_id]=object_id('<yourtable>'); 

set @Sql_Str=SUBSTRING(@Sql_Str,1,len(@Sql_Str)-6);
exec(@Sql_Str)
```

I cannot get that query to work however. My table has 118 columns. I think that may be more data than the query above may handle.

Comment: Maybe it should be varchar(max) rather than varchar(8000)?

Comment: That did actually work. Thanks Magnus.

Comment: However, I see it put all the values into a single column. I need the distinct values specified per column.

Comment: Is there any way to write one dynamic statement for that instead of having to write one subquery per column?

Comment: This `select @Sql_Str=@Sql_Str+'something'` is called [quirky update](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5150/please-can-somebody-explain-how-quirky-updates-wor.html) and can have various side effects. [Starting with v2017 there is `STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql), with previous versions you should prefer the well discussed XML approach.

Comment: The string length of the concatenation is about 93 characters.  93 * 118 columns = 10974 chars.  But your @Sql_Str variable is only holds 8000 characters.  You just need to increase the size of the variable as Magnus suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(500)='dbo';
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(500)='SomeTable';

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (
            SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''' AS TableSchema '
                 + ',''' + c.TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TableName '
                 + ',''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS ColumnName '
                 + ',''' + c.DATA_TYPE + ''' AS ColumnType '
                 + ',CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME)+' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Value ' 
                 + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME)
                 + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NOT NULL ' 
                 + ' GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' ' 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
            WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName
              AND TABLE_SCHEMA=@Schema
              --exclude not supported types
              --AND c.DATA_TYPE NOT IN('xml') --add more types
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,10,'')
);
--PRINT @cmd
EXEC(@cmd);
```

This statement will first create a long list of `UNION ALL SELECT` with `GROUP BY` (better than `DISTINCT`) as dynamically created SQL and executes this with `EXEC()`.

You can decomment `PRINT` to examine the statement created.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in tSQL:

```
declare @table_name varchar(55)
set @table_name= 'IV00101' ---- <-- Change this to your table name
create table #colcount (
    colname varchar(55),
    dct int,
    tot int
)
create table #colContent (
    colname varchar(55),
    col_val nvarchar(max),
    col_val_count int
)
create table #sqlexecs( s varchar(max))
declare @col_name varchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max), @sql2 nvarchar(max)
declare c cursor for 
select name from sys.columns where [object_id]=object_id(@table_name)
open c
fetch next from c into @col_name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'select cn.name, count(distinct '+@col_name+') as dct_numrow, count('+@col_name+') as tot_numrow from '+@table_name+' join (select name from sys.columns where name = '''+@col_name+''' and [object_id]=object_id('''+@table_name+''')) cn on cn.name = '''+@col_name+''' group by cn.name'
    set @sql2 = 'select ' +@col_name+', count('+@col_name+') as colvalcnt from '+@table_name+' group by '+@col_name
    --insert into #sqlexecs values (@sql) --uncomment to  view sql selects produced by @sql
    --insert into #sqlexecs values (@sql2) --uncomment to  view sql selects produced by @sql2
    insert into #colcount execute sp_executesql @sql
    ------
    declare @d int, @t int
    set @d = (select dct from #colcount where colname = @col_name)
    set @t = (select tot from #colcount where colname = @col_name)
    if (@d <> @t) 
    begin
        insert into #colContent (colname) values (@col_name)
        insert into #colContent (col_val,col_val_count) execute sp_executesql @sql2
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into #colContent values (@col_name,1,1)
    end
    fetch next from c into @col_name
end
close c
deallocate c


--select * from #sqlexecs -- uncomment to view sql code produced by @sql and @sql2
select * from #colcount --order by dct desc
select * from #colContent

drop table #colcount
drop table #colContent
drop table #sqlexecs
```

The first table shows column name, distinct value count, and total value count. 
The second table shows column name, distinct values, and the number of times a distinct value appears. If values in column are all distinct (column is a candidate key), colname | 1 | 1 is shown. 
 
This should work if copy/pasted, please let me know it doesn't. Dev for  use in Dynamics GP.